# Analysis Services Project Deployment Issue in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: ssas, visual-studio-2019

I am unable to deploy Analysis Services Multidimensional and Data Mining Project on Visual Studio 2019. It tells me to ensure that "SQL Browser" service is running while Administrative Tools are showing "running" status for SQL Server Browser.

Comment: The oldest solution for such issues -- Have you tried restarting the machine ? Are you able to connect via SSMS ?